# Lognormal distribution notation

Tags: probability-distributions, matlab

I have a problem where there is a lognormal variate, S = LN(30, 0.33).

The Matlab code specified in the text to generate 10,000 sample values for S is S=lognrnd(log(30),.33,10000,1).

My question is why is there log(30) in the code. Should it just not be 30?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognrnd.html) states that the first argument $\mu$ is the mean of the **log**-values (equivalently the log of the geometric means of values). Start by explaining what the arguments mean in the expression $\operatorname{LN}(30, 0.33)$.

Comment: I went through the text, and oddly enough, the 30 refers to the median, and 0.33 is the COV.